# What norm on $\mathbb C (z)$

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

There are several different ways to define a norm on the space of polynomials $\mathbb C [z]$. For example, $\|p\| = \sup_{|z|\le 1}|p(z)|$ defines a norm.

If $\mathbb C (z)$ denotes the field of quotients, my question is, what is the norm on $\mathbb C (z)$? I understand $\mathbb C [z]\hookrightarrow \mathbb C (z)$ so that the norm on $\mathbb C (z)$ must somehow extend the norm $\|p\|$ on $\mathbb C [z]$. My problem with that is that defining $\|p/q\| = \sup_{|z|\le 1}|p(z)/q(z)|$ does not work because $q$ can be zero.

Comment: No, $q$ cannot be zero.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil I believe he meant $q$ can *have* a zero

Comment: Dear @Marc: norms on a normed space are not allowed to take the value $\infty$ . The supremum does not work and no amount of tinkering will make it work. Also, why single out  $z=0$ ? A rational function, like say  $\frac {1}{x-z}$, can have a pole at any $z\in \mathbb C$.

Comment: I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no reasonable norm for $\mathbb C(z)$.

But maybe make it a complete metric space like this:  Consider elements of $\mathbb C(z)$ to be continuous maps of the Riemann sphere to itself.  Use uniform convergence (with respect to a metric for the Riemann sphere).